# Breaking and aligning equations

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, align

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin \\
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \delta \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \\ 
                       &\hphantom{{}=} \delta^2\sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How do I align the last equation with the two above it? I have previously had success with `phantom`, but doesn't work here.

Comment: not sure why you're loading `amsfonts` twice.  actually, since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, all you need is `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}`.  loading these particular packages multiple times shouldn't cause problems, but it's likely to cause confusion for unwary newbies who may want to copy your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or use `\hphantom{{}={}}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin \\
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \delta \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \\ 
                       &\hphantom{{}={}} \delta^2\sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A better option would be to indent successive lines of an expression that breaks across lines, so it becomes clear that it's the continuation of a previous expression; something like

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin \\
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \delta \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \\ 
                       &\hphantom{{}={}}\quad\delta^2\sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

use `\mathrel{...}`

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \sin \\
\sum_i{ c_i}           &= \delta \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \\ 
                       &\mathrel{\hphantom{=}}\delta^2\sin\cos \cos \sin\cos \sin\cos \cos 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I typically use

```
\begin{align}
  ... = {} & ... \\
      = {} & ... \\
           & ...
\end{align}
```

note the set of `{}` between the `=` and the `&` a lot faster to type than `\phantom` and friends

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the packages loaded; [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\sum_{i}c_{i}
&= \cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\sin\\
\sum_{i}c_{i}
&= \delta\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\cos\sin\cos\\ 
&\hphantom{{}={}} \delta^{2}\sin\cos\cos\sin\cos\sin\cos\cos 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]